# Python function to display the highest occurring number, if there is a tie return both. num = [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,4,5,4,4,4]

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, word-frequency

I made this Python code to store the key and values in the dictionary

```
num = [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,4,5,4,4,4] 
dict1 = {}
for val in num:
    if val in dict1:
      dict1[val] = dict1[val] + 1
    else:
        dict1[val] = 1;

print(max(dict1,key=dict1.get))
```

Max function is returning the first value it encounters. Please advise what to do in case of a tie.

Thanks!

Comment: `max` only returns one value

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `Counter`

```py
from collections import Counter

my_list = [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,4,5,4,4,4] 

highest = Counter(my_list).most_common()[0] # will be (2,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,4,5,4,4,4] 
dict1 = {}
maxfreq = 0
for val in num:
    if val in dict1:
      dict1[val] = dict1[val] + 1
      if(dict1[val]>maxfreq):
            maxfreq = dict1[val]
    else:
        dict1[val] = 1
        if(dict1[val]>maxfreq):
            maxfreq = dict1[val]
            
for i in dict1:
    if(dict1[i]==maxfreq):
        print(i)
```

I am basically storing the value of maximum frequency and reiterating over the dictionary to print all the keys whose value matches the maximum frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to get all the desired values in a list.

```
num = [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,4,5,4,4,4] 
dict1 = {}
for val in num:
    if val in dict1:
      dict1[val] = dict1[val] + 1
    else:
        dict1[val] = 1;

maxkey = max(dict1,key=dict1.get)
print([key for key in dict1 if dict1[key]==dict1[maxkey]])
```

Output:

```
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary here might be a overstretch. You could implement this functionality in linear time without additional module.

```
nums = [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,4,5,5,5,4,4] 

def max_in_list(nums):
    max_list = []
    max_value = 0
    for i in nums:
        if i > max_value:
            max_list = [i]
            max_value = i
        elif i == max_value:
            max_list.append(i)
    return max_list

assert max_in_list(nums) == [5,5,5]

print(max_in_list(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I must be missing the point here, because I see some very elaborate solutions to what looks to me like a simple problem.

```
def maxes(nums):
    return [m for m in nums if m == max(nums)]

>>> nums = [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,4,5,5,5,4,4]
>>> maxes(nums)
[5, 5, 5]

>>> nums = [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,4,5,5,5,4,4,6]
>>> maxes(nums)
[6]
```